# Capture and append in Twig

Tags: templates, symfony, twig

What I need is to append text blocks to the same name in any template and finally print its value.

What I have so far.

In child template:

```
{% set tmp %}
...some text...
{% endset %}

{% set capture = capture|default([])|merge([tmp]) %}
```

In parent (main layout):

```
{{ capture|default([])|join|raw }}
{# it works in the same template but not in parent #}
```

I know it is ugly but still would be happy if it worked.

Ideally I'd like to make an extension to work like this:

```
{% capture %}
...some text...
{% endcapture %}
{# to capture #}

{% capture() %}
{# to print #}
```

but documentation that I've seen (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html) does not help.

I don't know what type of extension should I choose, where actual data manipulations are made, how I access and append data.

What existing extension could I use as a base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't access even Twig global variable set in sf config.

So created 2 Twig functions: one to append content, another to get what is buffered.

Using twig extension class property as "global var" because container params turned out to be locked.

Usage:

1. set content to local var
2. append local var to global var
3. get and print raw global var content